# How to print some text after the last data of every month?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a table, in my table data November 2019 has three dates, December 2019 has two dates and January 2020 has one date. I wanted to print("End of the month") on the last date of every month. In my code, it printed after the first date of every month.

I got the following output from my code:

```
2019-11-2
End of the month
2019-11-28
2019-11-30
2019-12-25
End of the month
2019-12-28
2020-01-30
End of the month
```

I wanted the output like as follows:

```
2019-11-2
2019-11-28
2019-11-30
End of the month
2019-12-25
2019-12-28
End of the month
2020-01-30
End of the month
```

My codes are as follows:

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime

conn = sqlite3.connect("mydatabase.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()

table = cursor.execute("""
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS product_transfer(`date_of_transfer` DATE);
""")

cursor.execute("""
INSERT INTO product_transfer(`date_of_transfer`)VALUES
  ('2019-11-2'),
  ('2019-11-28'),
  ('2019-11-30'),
  ('2019-12-25'),
  ('2019-12-28'),
  ('2020-01-30');
""")

information = cursor.execute("SELECT *FROM product_transfer").fetchall()
printed = set()
for i in information:
    b = (i[0])
    print(b)
    date = datetime.strptime(b, "%Y-%m-%d")
    if str(date.month) + str(date.year) not in printed:
        printed.add(str(date.month) + str(date.year))
        print('End of the month')
```

Comment: add `order by date_of_transfer` to your `select` it will make sure the data is sorted by date

Comment: @balderman I add order by date_of_transfer, but how can I get the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
prevMonth = 0

for i in information:
    b = (i[0])
    month = int(b.split('-')[1]) #assuming that b is a string
    
    date = datetime.strptime(b, "%Y-%m-%d")
    if str(date.month) + str(date.year) not in printed:
        printed.add(str(date.month) + str(date.year))
        if prevMonth and month != prevMonth:
           print('End of the month')
    print(b)
    prevMonth = month
```

You just need to handle the last case which is not printed here.

Comment: I wanted to print("End of the month") on the last date of every month, but in your code, it not printed on the last date of last month.

Comment: I mentionned that at the end of my post : you must check if it is required (to avoid printing the sentence two consecutive times) and, if it is, print the sentence one more time after the end of the loop.

Comment: ok, it works, thanks!

Comment: Usually we mark an answer that was useful with the upvote button. Thanks !